# Covariance of some random variables

Tags: variance, random-variable, expected-value, covariance

I am given 2n-1 random variables, namely X₁, X₂... Xₙ, Xₙ₊₁... X₂ₙ₋₁. I also have E(Xᵢ)= and Var(Xᵢ)=² for i=1,2,...2n-1. Suppose Y=X₁+X₂+...+Xₙ and W=Xₙ+Xₙ₊₁+...+X₂ₙ₋₁ and I am asked to calculate Cov(Y,W).

I tried solving it by Cov(Y,W)=E(YW)-E(Y)E(W), and I can easily solve for E(Y) and E(W) since E(Xᵢ)= is given in the question. However, how do I go about solving for E(YW) since it is not stated in the question that the 2n-1 variables are independent? I am thus unable to assume that E(YW)=E(Y)E(W). Or is there another way to solve this question without having to use this formula?

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. Could you format your question using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)?

Comment: Hint: Even if the $X_i$'s are independent, $\mathbb E[YW]\ne\mathbb E[Y]\mathbb E[W]$

Comment: All you need to know is that [covariance is bilinear.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=bilinear%20covariance)  In this particular problem, the resulting calculations are easy (because they involve only products of ones, which are simple to compute!).